# WSAGetLastError does not pass Windows App Certification Kit Test

Tags: sockets, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, getlasterror, wack

According to the [`WSAGetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580.aspx) documentation, it is supported for Windows Store apps on Windows 8.1.

However, I am getting the following error from Windows App Certification Kit - Test Results:

> -API WSAGetLastError in wsock32.dll is not supported for this application type

I am developing a Windows Store app in Windows 8.1.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you linking your app to wsock32.dll directly?  If so, you should be linking to Ws2_32.dll instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks very much! It worked! I had two libraries, wsock32.lib and Ws2_32.lib as input to my linker...:-( I removed wsock32.lib and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because a wrong library (wsock32.lib) was linked.

I had two libraries, wsock32.lib and Ws2_32.lib as input to my linker...:-( I removed wsock32.lib and it worked.

Thanks goes to Remy Lebeau (https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau).